# Detect compatibility of the new Html5 tag <mark>

Tags: css, html, dom, tags

How can I detect the compatibility of the new tag .I'm using a method like this (with jQuery):

```
var $mark = $('<mark>');
$mark.appendTo('html');
var bg = $mark.css('background');
if (/rgb\(255\, 255\, 0\)/.test(bg)) return true;
else return false;
```

But the problem is it return false in firefox nightly, even it is supported.
I inspect the mark element, found that other browsers(chrome, safari) will add a style for this tag automatically which includes a background-color and a color.

[image]

Unfortunately firefox haven't add style for the tag what chrome and safari do. But the tag also has a yellow background.

[image]
[image]

So I'm confused how it can be yellow although no other style added to it.
And does anyone have a solid way to detect the compatibility of it in browsers?
Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. My first thought, obviously, was that Firefox refused to cooperate with you inserting a mark in the wrong position, but even after correcting the error, it still says false. I'll have to do more checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your routine is that Firefox can't use shorthand properties like `background` in that context.

Solution: use `backgroundColor`.

```javascript
var $mark = $('<mark>');
$mark.appendTo('body');
var bg = $mark.css('backgroundColor');
if (/rgb\(255\, 255\, 0\)/.test(bg)) return true;
else return false;
```

This will work in Firefox and Chrome.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HCps5/1/).

Note, however, that `<mark>` is not formally defined as having a yellow background colour. The fact that all browsers currently display it like that, doesn't mean that it's guaranteed to keep working in the future.

Comment: Works for me. Your are right, browsers may change the display.It just work around. But why it shows yellow without any extra style added to it.